# ReactJs how to redirect to next page with response i.e. with session

Tags: reactjs

How to redirect to next page after login in reactJs? I am using axios for that. I have started my session on server side and on client side reactJs I am getting response.  I want restrict my todo page.  Only after login it should be redirect to todo page with session.

So how to redirect with this session response?

**login.jsx**

```
axios.post('/login', {
  email:this.state.strEmail,
  password:this.state.strPassword
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);//this session respons
  //location.href='/todoapp';
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

**app.jsx**

```
ReactDOM.render(

      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Main}>
            <Route path="RegistrationForm" component={RegistrationForm}/>

            <Route path="todoapp" component={TodoApp}/>
            <IndexRoute component={Login}/>
        </Route>
      </Router>, 
      document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Is your `location.href` not working?

Comment: It is Working. But i want redirect  /location.href='/todoapp'; with session. which i recieved fom response

Comment: If I am right you want something like this: `/todoapp/sessionValue` ?

Comment: yes ..kind of like this. and how to restrict that todoapp in app.jsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app.jsx you can add extra parameter in route as:

```
<Route path="todoapp/:sessionValue" component={TodoApp} />
```

It will assure that, the url `todoapp` will not open without the extra parameter `sessionValue`. If you want it optional, then you can do this as: `path="todoapp(/:sessionValue)"`.

And in your login.jsx you can pass the session parameter as:

```
location.href = '/todoapp/sessionValue';
```

OR

```
browserHistory.push('/todoapp/sessionValue');
```

Comment: It shows this error SyntaxError: expected expression.When i add location.href='/todoapp/:sessionValue'; and <Route path="todoapp/:sessionValue" component={TodoApp}/>

Comment: It works with browserHistory.push('/todoapp/sessionValue');Thank you so much.

Comment: sorry for disturbing you again but am not getting sessionValue. on todoapp.jsx

Comment: @vaishnaviaher What error is showing ? Or how are you trying to get the value of session through response?

Comment: var urlValue=this.props.params.sessionValue;
  alert(urlValue);

Comment: @vaishnaviaher I think you should add another question with more details like from where you are sending that `props` and what values are under `params`. This way you will get more proper answers.

Comment: I think browserHistory.push('/todoapp/sessionValue');not redirect with the sessionvalue. only redirect with variable name not with value which is assign

Comment: @vaishnaviaher yes, at the place of `sessionValue` you should use the value which you want to send on `todoapp` page.

Comment: @vaishnaviaher No problem, you can use that (if you want).